# Does Google Search Console respect rel="nofollow" when doing validations?

Tags: google, google-search-console, mobile, nofollow

I have a 3 links on my site that are throwing failures in the Mobile Usability section of the [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about) for:

- Text too small to read
- Viewport not set

Google has no need to crawl these pages so I have added a `rel="nofollow"` on the three links, e.g. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en

I would like to know if the Google Search Console will respect this field when performing a new validation/test on my site?

Comment: Have you tried adding _disallow_ directives to your [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en) for these URLs? You can then try Fetch as Google to crawl them to see that's working (which it should).

Comment: @dan Thanks for the comment. I don't have a `robots.txt` at the moment and adding the `rel="nofollow"` to the link seemed to be doing the same thing, at least to my understanding. My question is more around whether specifically the GSC will respect this if I trigger a re-validation manually to correct errors.

Comment: No problem. Good question - in theory I'd agree, but I really don't know, maybe someone else has tested this.

Comment: nofollow on a link seems to discourage Google adding the destination to it's crawl list. But the URL could get added via other links, a sitemap etc. It will not spot a URL being discovered, crawled or indexed.

Comment: Do you want Google to not index a page so it does not show in search? If that is the case then adding a robots meta tag set to noindex to the page is your best move.